# Good C++ library for HTTPS connection ? Certificate is signed by a certificate autority

Tags: c++, ssl, https, certificate-authority

I have 2 questions:

Q1 : Does anyone know a good **C++ library** to perform requests towards a HTTPS server?

Note that the SSL certificate on the server will be provided by a **certificate autority** like VeriSign.

Q2 : So, could I embedded the root certificate of the CA in my C++ application so that it will be automatically used by the library? I don't want the user to add it manually in its operating system.

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- libcurl (C++ library here: http://code.google.com/p/curlpp/)
- PoCo Networking [PDF, pg. 36+](http://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf)

would both be able to use openssl. You can make it use CA certs provided by your application. I don't think it is easy to use *embedded resources*

Comment: Sehe, do both of them work for sending info to a remote client via HTTPS? I need to control my C++ program and query some options via a mobile phone.

Comment: Erm yes. The question was "Does anyone know a good C++ library to perform requests towards a HTTPS server?". So yes, you can send info (requests) to a HTTPS server.

Comment: Well; it seems cURL does not support HTTP server!! http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Can_I_write_a_server_with_libcur

Comment: @TinaJasmin Ah. That's (obviously) different! "sending info to a remote client" does **not** require a server. If you do, PoCo does implement this, Boost Asio and CppNetlib should get you there too with some more work

Comment: Ummm, OK, I guess. Can you provide an example of how it works? Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973159/remote-control-of-c-program-in-ubuntu-12-04-via-https

Answer (score 0):

I guess [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is one of the better known networking libraries out there.  In my experience being written in C (with all the wheel reinventing that that brings) it has proven to be crash-prone at times and doesn't have the nicest of APIs.  That said though, it's used in a ton of places, is relatively easy to get to grips with, and supports just about everything you could ever need.

Answer (score 0):

ON WIndows,There is a small library, or rather just a small set of c++ headrs:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66625/A-Fully-Featured-Windows-HTTP-Wrapper-in-C