# Remote control of C++ program in Ubuntu 12.04 via HTTPS

Tags: c++, servlets, ubuntu, networking, https

I have an emulator program written in C++ running on Ubuntu 12.04. There are some settings and options needed for running the program, which are given by the main's arguments. I need to query and control these options via HTTPS from a remote machine/mobile device. I was wondering if someone can help me with that.

There should probably be some libraries for the ease, for example libcurl. I'm not sure how suitable it is for my case, but here is any example of connection setup in libcurl. It's **not a must** to use any libraries though; just the most efficient/simplest way.

```
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>


using namespace curlpp::options;

int main(int, char **)
{
    try
    {
        // That's all that is needed to do cleanup of used resources (RAII style).
        curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;

        // Our request to be sent.
        curlpp::Easy myRequest;

        // Set the URL.
        myRequest.setOpt<Url>("http://example.com");

        // Send request and get a result.
        // By default the result goes to standard output.
        myRequest.perform();
    }

    catch (curlpp::RuntimeError &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    catch (curlpp::LogicError &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the emulator needs to retrieve it's configuration from a remote server, yes? As opposed to a client launching the emulator remotely and passing in the correct arguments?

Comment: No, reverse! A client needs to retrieve the emulator's config via HTTPS. So probably there should be a loop inside the program listening to HTTP connections?!